# AWS Lambda (NET6): how to store parameter the same way as in appsettings.json?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-parameter-store

I have a AWS Lambda NET6 and it uses appsettings.json. Now I want to use AWS Parameter Store instead of appsettings.json to keep db connection string and other params.

How should I store parameter as I have in my appsettings.json :     "Cognito": {
"Authority": "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/eu-west-2_x51234567"
} ?
My app does not process it, it is read by authorization extensions. The question is: how it should be in AWS PS?

Comment: In the exact same way!? Or in whatever way your extension dictates it to be.

Comment: What the same way? It should be accessible by AWS extension

Comment: By what extension? What does the doc for that extension say?

Comment: I use .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration["Cognito:Authority"];  //<----

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store it by parameter store (AWS PS) key like this to just retrieve it with Singleton/Utility parameter store reader class for config:
`"Cognito": { "Authority": "<PARAMETER-STORE-KEY>" }`

OR

you can just store the whole JSON string in the AWS PS and convert it again during the config setup, but not ideal for large strings.

OR

Using `Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager`

Comment: You mean: parameter name: Cognito , value: { "Authority": "<PARAMETER-STORE-KEY>" } ? or another way?

Comment: For example, let's say you store this in PS:   
Name - `staging-cognito`    
Value - `https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/eu-west-2_x51234567`    
  
Your settings should be:   
`"Cognito": { "Authority": "staging-cognito" }`   

You can retrieve it by doing something like:   
`var cognitoConnection = _config.GetValue<string> 
(AwsPsUtility.Read("Cognito:Authority"))`  

or   
  
using ASP.NET options pattern

Comment: I use this piece of code .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {            options.Authority = Configuration["Cognito:Authority"]; //<----!

Comment: Right, you just need to retrieve it right there.

Comment: or you can do it this way:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-access-parameters-from-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store-in-net-6-web2/

Comment: Ok, thanx, again in this case in the AWS PS: parameter name = "Cognito: Authority", parameter value: "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/eu-west-2_x51234567" ?

Comment: So, if you are gonna use `Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager`, I believe you need to use slash to follow AWS parameter store hierarchy rule. Like this: `Cognito/Authority`. The above example is how to use individual parameter store key value pair.